# How to get database size with Qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to define my vector size with mysql database size in qt c++. After I execute my commands it returns 0 and get an error;

```
QMYSQLResult::data: column 1 out of range
```

in line:

```
int dbSize = query.value(1).toInt();
```

However when I execute sql command in mysql-workbench it says *15*

Here is my code blocks for get database size :

```
int databaseConn::getDbSize()
{
    QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM images");
    query.exec();
    query.next();

    if( query.lastError().isValid())
    {
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        QSqlDatabase::database().rollback();

        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int dbSize = query.value(1).toInt();

        qDebug() << dbSize;

        return dbSize;
    }
}
```

Could you please help me where is my mistake?

PS: I dont want to call whole db and count it like :

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM test");

query.record().count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` in `QVariant QSqlQuery::value ( int index ) const` means zero-based index of field in the select statement. In your case, the only field `count(*)` will have index 0:

```
int dbSize = query.value(0).toInt();
```

You can get fields' count from `QSqlRecord`:

```
qDebug() << query.record().count();
```

Comment: So if I execute `select name, surname from table;`  and if I want to get name I will use 0 and for surname I will use 1?